# Find X user idle time in script for all users without root access

Tags: linux, x11

I'm wondering whether it is possible to get the idle time for all users on a given linux system that I access via SSH.

```
who -Tu
```

works well for idle times of users in terminal but does not update idle times for a user in the Xwindow system.

```
xidletime
```

seems to do the job, but is not installed in our (debian linux) environment.

Is this possible in some other way?

I do not have root access on the target machine, cannot listen directly to keyboard/mouse inputs, and cannot install new software.

I do know that on a given target machine only one specific user (known to me) can use the desktop.

If I cannot get the precise time, can I -at least- find out (using standard non-root console tools) whether the connected screen is locked or in screensaver?

Why do I want to do this? I intend to create a hostlist to be used in an MPI parallel processing task. All of the host in our lab are dedicated desktop machines for a specific employee, but run mostly idle during the weekend/at night. Normally the users do not log out, but lock their screen when going away. Many machines are idle most of the daytime as well. I want to use completely idle machines for my computation whenever I need them while excluding those where a user is present.
Btw.: I'm open to other solutions to get this hostlist. Main objective is to avoid antagonizing coworkers by slowing down their computers.